# Tracking completed transactions on CiviCRM in Google Analytics

Tags: civicontribute, google

We have a Drupal site using CiviCRM and I would like to track how many times users go to our membership, subscription, and donation pages and then complete those respective transactions. In setting up a Google Analytics conversion goal, we successfully set up one for when someone lands on the pages, but apparently did not set it up correctly for the completion.

We set up three goals, with each counting how many people landed on a thank-you page (civicrm/contribute/transact?_qf_ThankYou_display=true) after coming from either the membership, subscription, or donation CiviContribute page respectively, as such:

[image]

But we're getting the exact same number for each goal, suggesting it's just counting how many times someone ends on the Thank-you page regardless of where they come from. As you can see from the third screenshot below, we are getting 135 for the Thank-you pages (Goal 4, 5, or 6 Completions), regardless of it being a Join, Subscribe, or Donate page that got them there. That number is close to what I'm seeing in Civi, though not exactly.

[image]
[image]

[image]

Any advice on how to fix that would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for the [webtracking](https://civicrm.org/extensions/google-analytics-event-and-e-commerce-tracking) extension.